# Retasked headphone jack stopped working

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, headphones, microphone

Yesterday I retasked one of my jacks because the normal headphone jack on the motherboard is damaged, and the front panel headphone jack requires Realtek drivers which are no longer supported (they don't compile properly). I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

The retasking was successful using `hdajackretask`. And the computer worked for most of the day and through several reboots. However when I booted up the computer this morning, it was no longer working properly. The sound panel in the corner was showing a mic + speaker slider whereas before it was just speaker. I figured something was reset so I ran the retask process again first doing a `Remove boot override`, reboot, then `Install boot override` with `Blue Line In, Rear side` marked as `Line out (Front)`, reboot. I've also attempted this on the other jacks.

Using `hda-jack-sense-test`, the jack is shown as working:

```
Pin 0x14 (Green Line Out): present = No
Pin 0x15 (Black Line Out): present = No
Pin 0x16 (Orange Line Out): present = No
Pin 0x17 (Grey Line Out): present = No
Pin 0x18 (Pink Mic): present = No
Pin 0x19 (Pink Mic): present = No
Pin 0x1a (Blue Line In): present = Yes
Pin 0x1b (Green HP Out): present = No
```

I've run `alsamixer` and auto mute is disabled. 
`pavucontrol` hasn't helped either. What should i do?